# Validation error with web.xml and weblogic.xml in WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic, xml-validation

I'm trying to deploy a web application on a WebLogic 12c server but I'm getting validation errors in the XML. I tried changing the version of the schema and namespace but it didn't work and I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong.

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">             
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/sgdem.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

My weblogic.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app version="1.0"
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <fast-swap>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </fast-swap>   
</weblogic-web-app>
```

The error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  <11:4> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'web-app@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' with element-only content type cannot have text content.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1482)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:245)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  <11:4> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'web-app@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' with element-only content type cannot have text content.
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:245)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:231)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:155)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:327)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:817)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred due to the web.xml of the application contained special character in the file. Before redeploy the application, do make sure the web.xml and weblogic.xml does not contain any special characters, unsupported tag or symbol in the file.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/sgdem.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">   
    <fast-swap>
        <enabled>false</enabled>        
    </fast-swap>
</weblogic-web-app>
```